# How to apply orthogonal polynomial transformation on an image for image compression?

Tags: matlab, image-compression

I am working on Image compression based on orthogonal polynomial transformation. My input image is gray scale image of size 256*256. i divide this image into 4 by 4 blocks. and than apply the orthogonal polynomial operator on each block. but I am not getting correct coefficient.
Example:

If I have a block `4x4` of Input image:

```
I=[5 11 8 10;9 8 4 12; 1 10 11 4;19 6 15 7];
```

and my polynomial operator for `n=4` is:

```
[M] = [p0 p1 p2 p3]=[1 -3 1 -3;1 -1 -1 9;1 1 -1 -9;1 3 1 3]
```

After finding the outer product:

```
[20 -24 24 -16; -24 84 -80 24;24 -80 84 -24;-16 24 -24 20]
```

when I applied this on input image blocks, my answer is:

```
[-396 172 88 -104; 1012 -248 -376 616 -972 320 436 -552; 492 -104 4 172]
```

which is wrong. It should be

```
[140 0 -6 -10; 32 -112 2 -174; 22 -30 8 -40;34 -54 84 -8]
```

what I have done wrong?

My MATLAB code to find orthogonal polynomial operator is given below.

```
clc
clear all
close all
ID=imread('cameraman.tif');  % input image
I=double(ID);
imshow(ID);
[r,c]=size(I);
y1=zeros(r,c);
x=1:4;
n=4;
mu=(n+1)/2;
p0=[1 1 1 1];
p1=x-mu;
p2=(x-mu).^2-(n.^2-1)/12;
p3=(x-mu).^3-((x-mu)*(3*n.^2-7))/20;
P=[p0;p1; p2; p3];
N=[1 1 1 1;-1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5;1 -1 -1 1;-0.3 0.9 -0.9 0.3];
M=[1 1 1 1;-3 -1 1 3;1 -1 -1 1;-3 9 -9 3]; % after sacling
v=M';
O=M.*v;
T=O'; % Orthogonal polynomial operator
 for i=1:4:r
  for j=1:4:c
    y1(i:i+3,j:j+3)=I(i:i+3,j:j+3).*(double(T));
    end
 end
 figure,imshow(uint8(y1))
 y1
```

Comment: OK, so where's your code to show us what you tried? **Why** is it not correct?  **SHOW US**.

Comment: From the rules: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].*"

Comment: I mentioned the code to find the orthogonal polynomial operator

Comment: Your code does not generate the `M` in your example, nor does it show how you're applying the operator. Please provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok now i write my code here and plz let me know where i have done wrong

Comment: So what is the output you get for your code and what output do you expect? Frankly, I don't know what "image compression based on orthogonal polynomial transformation" is, but I'm pretty sure that at least part of your problem is that you're applying the outer product (a vector operation) to a matrix. I even went so far as to look up a paper that seems similar and from skimming that it seems that `O` should be a series of 9 matrices for the 3x3 case.

Comment: And opening multiple duplicate questions is not productive. If you don't get the answers you're looking for, you should clarify your question (and perhaps even narrow the scope) to make it more answerable.

Comment: I am not getting the right value of orthogonal polynomial coefficient  (which is output y1 matrix  in Matlab code). The orthogonal polynomial  operator when apply on an image must be given first coefficient value maximum which is the DC component and rest are AC component but in my case I  am not getting desired coefficient value . while when i apply other transformation such as dct, wavelets on an image i am getting the desired result. the paper link(http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885608001790)